# Convert Filetime to time (from variable) PHP

Tags: php, filetime

I have a filetime time of `'131841804730412861'`
**I do not have a file, I have a filetime coming from an API**
I am trying to convert it to a "normal" time

Is there a way to decode filetime from a varible in php seeing as Microsoft Filetime has an epoch of Jan 1, 1601 and uses microseconds?

Comment: Did you google the function you are trying to use? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: seems like there is to many numbers tho

Comment: It might be a lot of numbers but it does decode to an actual date - https://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=131841804730412861&inputformat=filetime

Comment: Why on earth do you need a filetime that dates back to 1601? That is several hundred years before any computer was invented. What kind of "file" is this filetime from?

Comment: I must have misworded it, I was just saying that Microsoft Filettimehas an epoch of Jan 1, 1601

Comment: ahh - convert that shit to Unix

Comment: https://www.tehplayground.com/PULfwnOLYnf9arrx

Comment: @Stender That one works perfectly. I had tried some of the solutions from the dupes but they returned the incorrect time.

Comment: @ChristopherTaylor No they don't see my link. Maybe it's timezone related?

Comment: weird.. We are in the same timezone @Andreas..

Comment: @Stender But not the servers (?). PHP is a serverside language not clientside.

Answer (score 0):

date(); takes format as first argument  [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Mainly You want to do something like:

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
```

btw. Number You gave in question is too large.

Answer (score -1):

`filemtime` — Gets file modification time and it returns the time the file was last modified, or **FALSE** on failure. The time is returned as a **Unix timestamp**, which is suitable for the `date()` function.

So, this should work for you but I've a doubt that your given string '**131841804730412861**' is a valid unix timestamp because too high in lenght.

```
date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
```